# Proof of a "generic" criterion of root on series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So basically i have to prove that for $A = \lim_{n\to \infty}inf\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$
that if $A>1$ the serie $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.
So for $ε=k - A$ and $A>1$ $A = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ that means that there is afinite amount of terms of $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$
under $k = A - ε$
So there is a real number $n_0< n$ so that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} > k$

I really dont know where im going with this what is next or have i started completely on the wrong foot.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Proof

Comment: @MartinR made a fix to my question had forgotten the inf

Comment: Your criterion is weaker than the root test: If $\liminf_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} > 1$ then $\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}  \ge \liminf_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}  > 1$.